# Blazor Role Management Add Role trough UI (Crud)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crud, blazor

I'm pretty new to blazor and have gotten myself in some doubt on adding roles to the database.
I have implemented to Identity role management and have a working system.
But now i want to add new roles trough the GUI instead of editing the database.

I have a razor page called RolesOverview.razor
On this page i have a input field and a button.
When i click this button i want to add the text to the roles manager and save it to the database.

This is my razor component

```
@page "/admin/roles"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <!-- Roles Overview Group Box -->
    <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="display-6">Roles Options</h1>
            <hr class="my-4" />
            <div class="row" style="background-color:white; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px;">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card w-100 mb-3" style="min-width:100%;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Roles</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-1">
                                        Role Name:
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-10">
                                        <input type="text" style="min-width:100%;" placeholder="Role Type" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-1">
                                        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width:90px;">Add Role</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not Getting Saved...

```
  @code {
        private string CurrentValue { get; set; }

        private async void AddRole()
        {
            if (CurrentValue != string.Empty)
            {
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(CurrentValue))
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
                    {
                        Name = CurrentValue
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I have no clue on what todo next.
I's it posible todo it with razor component or do i need to do it trough razor page?

Example would be perfect.

Regards Me!

Answer (score 2):

Answer :

```
                                    <div class="col-10">
                                        <input value="@CurrentValue" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => CurrentValue =__e.Value.ToString())" />

                                        @*<input type="text" style="min-width:100%;" placeholder="Role Type" />*@
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-1">
                                        <a @onclick="AddRole" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width:90px;">Add Role</a>
                                    </div>
```

@code {
private string CurrentValue { get; set; }

```
        private async void AddRole()
        {
            if (CurrentValue != string.Empty)
            {
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(CurrentValue))
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
                    {
                        Name = CurrentValue
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RoleManager to create a new role by using the [CreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) method:

```
if (!await roleMgr.RoleExistsAsync("RoleName"))
{
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
    {
        Name = "RoleName"
    });
}
```