# Unable to create a Role using RoleManager in Blazor Serverside

Tags: roles, blazor-server-side

I had some code using the RoleManager that I had copied from an MVC project to create roles in a Blazor project.
It compiles okay but when I step through the code it gets to that line and then appears to throw and exception, as it doesn't ever go to the next line.  I am unable to catch an exception though.

Since my code didn't work I found code on the web and it behaved the same, so I changed how it was injected and I got a different error, so I found a third way of doing it and that too gets to the line that tests to see if there is a role already existing and blows up.

Here is the latest attempt

```
  [Inject]
    IServiceProvider services {get;set;}
    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        using (var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>())
        {
            string proRole = "Pro";
           
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(proRole))
            {
                var temp = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = proRole });
            }
            
        }
    }
```

And it blows up on the awaited if statement.

Here is the previous code that should work that doesn't.

```
 string proRole = "Pro";
                string proClientRole = "ProClient";
                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(proRole))
                {
                    var temp = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = proRole });
                }
```

which is inside of a method.

I also had it as @{code in the Razor file and after an hour of trying different things there I moved it to a base class because they have been more stable in the past.

It is not the database connection because that is well verified and also because UserManager is called in the same class and it work

I also tried this code ([Blazor Role Management Add Role trough UI (Crud)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172239/blazor-role-management-add-role-trough-ui-crud))  both suggestions.

This is one bad thing about Blazor for me is it is buggy I never know if it is my bad, or just something wrong with the latest greatest.  But I am assuming it is my bad in this case.

Anyway any help would be much appreciated, I am way too many hours on this,

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted the same code to the "/" page and it works there.
For some reason it wouldn't work in a component loaded into a component but the standard Role code works as expected in the "/" page.
Most likely I should have restarted my computer as it now works in the original location too.